# JSON schema не проходит валидацию

Tags: python, json, api, flask

написал простой JSON api которое должно умножать цифры, но почему не работает когда отправить не полный запрос типа:

```
curl -X POST -d '{"token": 1, "a": 1}' http://localhost:6543/product
curl -X POST -d '{ }' http://localhost:6543/product
```

Он возвращает не ошибку 400, а 500. А иногда даже на правильный запрос отправляет или 400 или 500

Правильный запрос выглядит так:

```
curl -X POST -d '{"token": 1, "a": 1, "b": 1}' http://localhost:6543/product
```

Код:

---

```
from flask import Flask, request, abort, jsonify
from jsonschema import validate, ValidationError

POSITIVE_INTEGER_SCHEMA = {
    "type": "integer",
    "exclusiveMinimum": 0
}

def object_schema(*properties):
    return {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {key: POSITIVE_INTEGER_SCHEMA for key in properties},
        "additionalProperties": False,
        "requiredProperties": properties
    }

INPUT_SCHEMA = object_schema("token", "a", "b")

OUTPUT_SCHEMA = object_schema("token", "product")

validate(instance={
  "token": 1234567890,
  "a": 4718923648912376,
  "b": 4710943190713794
}, schema=INPUT_SCHEMA)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/product', methods=['POST'])
def product():
    json = request.get_json(force=True)

    if not json:
        abort(400)

    try:
        validate(instance=json, schema=INPUT_SCHEMA)
    except ValidationError as e:
        print("invalid: ", e)
        abort(400)
    else:
        token, a, b = (json[k] for k in ("token", "a", "b"))
        r = {"token": token, "product": a*b}
        validate(instance=r, schema=OUTPUT_SCHEMA)
        return jsonify(r)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
    server = make_server('', 6543, app)
    server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: 500 - ошибка на сервере, вот в `token, a, b = (json[k] for k in ("token", "a", "b"))` оно и падает, если нет чего-то...

Comment: @Jack_oS а почему не работает ```try: validate(instance=json, schema=INPUT_SCHEMA) except ValidationError as e: print("invalid: ", e) abort(400)``` Ведь если не подходит по схеме, то должно выдать ошибку 400

Comment: оно работает, только в validate() не возникает ошибок и try уходит в else